# How to add class to random element if condition satisfy jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a random class for one element at a time. Thats perfectly working for me. But i need to check a condition that if 'checked' class present avoid that p tag and add a random class for another element.

```
<p class='per'>Hello</p>
<p class='per'>Hola</p>
<p class='per changed'>abc</p>
<p class='per'>abc</p>
<p class='per changed'>djjd</p>
<p class='per'>sss</p>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var paras = $('.per');
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * paras.length);
    paras.eq(rand).addClass('random');
});
```

Comment: Change `var paras = $('.per');` to `var paras = $('.per:not(.checked)');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery's hasClass method to see if has class changed or not. Here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/peteTalksWeb/pen/zvwXgq)

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    addRandomClass();
});

function addRandomClass() {
  var paras = $('.per');
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * paras.length);
  if(!paras.eq(rand).hasClass('changed')) {
    paras.eq(rand).addClass('random');
  } else {
    addRandomClass();
  }
}
```